# React not rendering css styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to add a dropdown menu to my application and I picked Selectize (https://github.com/furqanZafar/react-selectize). But it appears that it is not displayed correctly on the page. [This is what is looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLLhe.png), it seems that the css styles are missing. I am quite a rookie to React so please bear with me if this is not a smart question. Thanks in advance!

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require("path")
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,

  entry: './assets/js/index', 

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
      filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
  },

  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader', query: { presets:['react'] }}, 
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader'},
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'css-loader', query: { modules: true, localIdentName: '[name]__[local]'}},
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
}
```

**Dropdown.js**

```
import {ReactSelectize, SimpleSelect, MultiSelect} from 'react-selectize';
import React from 'react';
import 'react-selectize/themes/index.css'


export default class Dropdown extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SimpleSelect placeholder="Select a fruit" onValueChange={value => alert(value)}>
                <option value = "apple">apple</option>
                <option value = "mango">mango</option>
                <option value = "orange">orange</option>
                <option value = "banana">banana</option>
            </SimpleSelect>
        )
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import Dropdown from "./components/dropdown"

var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')

ReactDOM.render(<Dropdown />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

**The following error was in the console:**

```
Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have 
refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created 
inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of 
React loaded
```

Comment: what is an error in console? May me your webpack configuration is missing something.

Comment: The error is "Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded", sounds like I'm running React many times?

Comment: i dont know if you already figured this out. but if you are using css-modules with a specific indentifier you should import it as ```import style from './file.css'``` then use it as ```<ReactComponent className={ style.myClass } />```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many react components, relevant CSS is included in the npm module, but cannot be loaded via `import` since they are not JS. Usually the styles have to be loaded separately.

The docs say:

> to include the default styles add the following import statement to your > stylus file: @import 'node_modules/react-selectize/themes/index.css'

Did you include that? If you aren't using Stylus, you could just grab the css and paste it into your main CSS file.

Comment: I actually included it directly in Dropdown.js. Sorry I forgot to include it in the code snippet above, updated. No luck yet.

Comment: I don't think you can import css that way with ES6? See second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923479/can-es6s-module-loader-also-load-assets-html-css

Also, this seems to address your exact issue: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/176

Comment: Thanks, I ended up including the css imports directly in the html.