# How to import a normalized path requiring "path"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm on Win10, and as you know, paths are a mess. I don't want to use backward slashes because that would make it too os-specific. I want to use "path", but I can't use it prior to imports.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
var path = require("path");
var bootstrapCSS = path.normalize('./src/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');
var fontCSS = path.normalize('./src/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
var seguiCSS = path.normalize('./src/assets/segui-info.css');
import bootstrapCSS
import fontCSS
import seguiCSS
```

How can I `import` normalized paths?

Comment: If you normalize a path and then export it. It will still be normalized when you import it to another file.

Comment: So, I should create a .js file exporting all my paths and import using from?

Comment: yes, that will work, but you have access to 'path' why not just require it and then normalize the paths the way you already are?

Comment: I tried to export them, but it treats them as mere variables instead of actually loading the CSS. The way I was doing does not work because it doesn't let me write code / normalize before importing.

Comment: I did some searching, ES6 import statements can't import CSS, but there are some libraries that can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923479/can-es6s-module-loader-also-load-assets-html-css

Comment: Are those css libraries installed in your `node_modules`?